# Reading terrain data from Google?

Tags: google-maps-api

Am I missing something or is it not possible to read terrain data (such as forests, roads, rivers, lakes, etc) through google?

I'm trying to create an app where you can walk in a scene dynamically created from terrain data from google - live/semi live.

Is this possible?

Comment: Terrain often means height, but it sounds like you just mean features. Have you thought of using OSM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, this is not possible in the Google Maps API. You can set the base map type to 'TERRAIN', but I don't think you can read what type of land type there is at a given coordinate. I would suggest looking into [Open Street Map (OSM)](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=19/51.49277/-0.12731) and the ['Landuse' tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Landuse).

Comment: Never heard about OSM before. Thanks i'll check it out.